# Dell U4323QE monitor not recognizing via USB-C on Acer Predator

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, windows-11, nvidia-graphics-card

I've bought a **Dell U4323QE monitor** and trying to set it up so that I can start using it. However, I'm not able to get my laptop (**Acer Predator Triton PT315-52 running on Windows 11 with Nvidia  GeForce RTX 2060**) displayed on the monitor by any method. I've installed the drivers, setup the display manager which is detecting the monitor however no display.

What's funny is that when I connect the USB-C, the LAN port connected to the monitor picks up on the laptop, and the monitor indicates that USB-C is connected but nothing else works.

I'm not able to figure out why this happens. My display settings shows that the display 1 (which is my laptop) connected to the inbuilt Intel display and the Dell monitor shows that its within Nvidia with no second display showing.

Please assist on how I can fix this.

Comment: There appear to be poorly-made or fake USB cables on the market. https://extendguide.com/all-about-usb-and-how-to-identify-fake-and-original/ Have you tried another cable?